# Why is my Time Ruler in After Effects displaying seconds like this?

Tags: after-effects, timecode

[image: Time Ruler]

I know that <kbd>Cmd</kbd> clicking on the **time stamp** in the left corner alternates between frames and seconds, but why are my seconds displayed like this? every other screen of the app I've seen with other users (on youtube tut's) it's a much more understandable 01s...02s....03s etc.

thanks!

Comment: I think you might have answered your own question?  When your timeline looks like that you are showing time in *frames*, not seconds.  If you CMD + click to change the setting from frames to seconds, the whole timeline should change as well.

Answer (score 4):

> I know that <kbd>Cmd</kbd> clicking on the time stamp in the left corner alternates between frames and seconds:

Thats exactly whats happening here.You switched to frames so After Effects is showing the frame count instead of a second count. Do a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> / <kbd>Cmd</kbd> click on the **time stamp** and you will get seconds:

[image]

To see *all time values* in the timeline simply drag the **zoom slider to the right** *or* use <kbd>Alt</kbd> and the **mousewheel** in order to 'zoom in':

[image]